# How to import text data into excel columns based on spaces?

Tags: python, excel

I need to write a python code that takes the text between two blank lines in a .txt file and inserts said text into unique columns in Excel, pasting the headers only once.  For example:

```
d1_type: 
shape: 
2, 

order: 
false, 

relation: 
true, 

d2_type: 
shape: 
false, 

order: 
false, 

relation: 
true, 

encoding_rt: 
6641, 

verification_rt: 
2429, 

target:  
2,"
```

So each cluster of text needs to be in its own column in excel (*Also, this page is formatting my text incorrectly--the words following each colon should be on their own line*). The main heading (e.g. order, relation, etc.) would ideally only be pasted once to name each column.  I'm really at a loss for how to do this.  I've googled it for the past 3 hours and made very little progress.

Comment: Some clusters had the line. How to parse they? Column header, cell value, and?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Parse each chunk
2. Convert each chunk into a dictionary
3. Finally, generate a CSV using your list of dictionaries.

You can then open the CSV in Excel. Something like the following.

## Parse Chunks

Given a filename, generate chunks.

```
def parse_chunks(filename):
   chunks = []
   with open(filename) as f:
      chunk = []
      for line in f:
         if line.strip().endswith('_type'):
            if chunk:
               chunks.append(chunk)
            chunk = [line]
         chunk.append(line)
   return chunks
```

## Dictionary-ify

Given chunks, generate a list of dictionaries.

```
def dictionarify(chunks):
   data = []
   for chunk in chunks:
      datum = {}
      key = None
      for line in chunk.splitlines():
          if line.endswith(':'):
              key = line.strip()[:-1]
          elif line.endswith(','):
              datum[key] = line.strip()[:-1]
          # implicitly ignores blank lines
      data.append(datum)
   return data
```

## Generate CSV

```
def generate_csv(data, dest):
    with open(dest, 'w') as f:

        headers = set()
        for datum in data:
            for key in datum:
                headers.add(key)
        headers = list(headers)  # arbitrarily establish order somehow 
        f.write(','.join(headers))

        for datum in data:
            f.write(','.join(datum[key] for key in headers))
```

You should then have a CSV that you can open in Excel.